# Jade - Template Engine: How to check if a variable exists

Tags: node.js, pug, express

I'm currently using Jade on a new project. I want to render a page and check if a certain variable is available.

`app.js`:

```
app.get('/register', function(req, res){
    res.render('register', {
        locals: {
          title: 'Register',
          text: 'Register as a user.',
        }
      });
});
```

`register.jade`:

```
- if (username)
p= username
- else
p No Username!
```

I always get the following error:

```
username is not defined
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: seems by now (2014), we no longer get this error. Much easier to use.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This should work:

```
- if (typeof(username) !== 'undefined'){
  //-do something
-}
```

Comment: - if (isset(username))' isset is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with PHP and Javascript. Updated my answer.

Comment: Tanks a lot! This Code works: - if (typeof username !== "undefined")

Answer (score 94):

Simpler than @Chetan's method if you don't mind testing for falsy values instead of undefined values:

```
if locals.username
  p= username
else
  p No Username!
```

This works because the somewhat ironically named [`locals`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a5) is the root object for the template.

Comment: This gives me a compiler error : 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'username'

Comment: @yourfriendzak - Are you sure your error is caused by this portion of your template?

Comment: Works perfect and it's better than using inline javascript, thanks.

Comment: I like this answer because this shows that Jade is whitespace sensitive language.

Comment: Careful this will only work if the variable was defined in the controller at the `render` stage: `res.render('view', {username: user.name});`

Answer (score 9):

```
if 'username' in this
    p=username
```

This works because res.locals is the root object in the template.

Answer (score 6):

If you know in advance you want a particular variable available, but not always used, I've started adding a "default" value to the helpers object.

```
app.helpers({ username: false });
```

This way, you can still do `if (username) {` without a catastrophic failure. :)

Comment: Thanks, though FYI for express 3.x this is now `app.locals({ username: false });`

Comment: Nice approach. Note that in Express 4.x `app.locals` is not a function anymore so it should be `app.locals.username = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler with pug, the successor to jade

```
if msg
  p= msg
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't 'username' be included in the locals object?

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/master/examples

Comment: Yes, but it still shouldn't return `undefined` if it's checked with `if` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Created a middleware to have the method `isDefined` available everywhere in my views:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isDefined = (variable) => {
    return typeof(variable) !== 'undefined'
  };  
  next();
};
```