# How to know the value is empty

Tags: node.js, pug

If I pass an empty array to jade, how can I know if is empty?

Javascript:

```
var data = [];
```

Jade:

```
if(data) 
   table ...
else 
   table ...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `length` property:

```
if (data.length)
    table ...
else
    table ...
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use javascript to check the length of the array.

```
if (data.length==0){
  // do something array is empty
}
```

here is a related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071150/3556874