# Checking for parameters in Jade mixin

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, pug, gulp

I'm trying to check whether a parameter was set when calling a Jade mixin. The following example does not work and I don't understand why.

```
mixin foo(bar)

  if bar
    - var text = 'a'
  else
    - var text = 'another'

  .hero-unit.macro-unit
    p This is #{text} mixin.


// Calling mixin:

+foo
+foo(bar)
+foo
+foo(bar)
```

**Expected output:**

```
This is a mixin.
This is another mixin.
This is a mixin.
This is another mixin.
```

**Actual output:**

```
This is a mixin.
This is a mixin.
This is a mixin.
This is a mixin.
```

I've also tried changing `if bar` to `if (typeof(username) !== 'undefined')` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071150), but no dice. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling the mixin and you are passing in bar. This is an undefined variable. If you were to change it to.

```
+foo
+foo('bar')
+foo
+foo('bar')
```

You will find that you would get the expected result.